# The Wolves - A Disappearing Storyline In The Walking Dead

Tags: the-walking-dead

So as I'm watching the Walking Dead for the millionth time, I'm still left wondering what the purpose of The Wolves was to the story?  They had left marks around the area that our main cast was at, but nothing really materialized until they attacked Alexandria, and by that point, they had all been killed except for about 6 of them I believe.

My question is, what was the point of their storyline?  Was it just a mere distraction or just a "bad guy" to fill up time until they figured out who their next bad guy was going to be?  It was so short lived, that it seems kinda sloppy and just thrown in there for some action.

I've seen the entire series so far, just re-watching it, so I know everything that happens after this, but maybe I'm missing a connection that I just didn't really see.

Comment: Thank goodness there was a group that didn't merit the never ending seasons of the other human threats. I kind of liked that they were here one day and gone the next. Seemed slightly more realistic to me than the next human threat conveniently out shining the last in craziness and all that.

Answer (score 2):

They are from the comics, but have been adapted for the tv-show. The clear intent and purpose for them is mainly around carol and morgan. As they both get pushed to the limit of their beliefs, Carol about murdering as much as she does, and Morgan if his way of showing mercy has a bad side to it.

I will include a link to [the comic book counterpart](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/The_Scavengers) if you are interested, 
as well as info regarding [Tv-Show wolves](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wolves)

Answer (score 0):

As far as the show goes, they are all killed. Five of them escaped the Alexandria because Morgan let's them after beating them at once. They are those attackers in next episode (I think S06E03) that attack Rick in the camper truck. Two he defeats inside camper, other 3 he sees in mirror so he shoots with automatic rifle through camper wall. Last one was Morgan's prisoner, shot by Carol and then turned and faced Morgan again.

I have to agree that after build up in season 5, it was quickly over with them. So besides prisoner causes clash between Carol and Morgan as another Kevin's answer already states, it is also the first time Alexandria is attacked by the living. This causes beliefs of people to change more rapidly as they realize how vulnerable they are and how dangerous actually the world is... and that Rick was right. After Wolves/herd attack, much more is put into defense, guard posts and weapon carrying sentry.